# need help on my query

Tags: mysql

i have one table : nobel(yr, subject, winner)

and i have this query : In which years was the Physics prize awarded but no Chemistry prize.

this is what i tried :
select distinct 
yr from nobel where subject='physics' and subject!='chemistry'

but is not working where i am going wrong.

see, i am not here to make my homework from someone. i am here to learn something. so, please give me suggetion.

Comment: In query where is applied on the Tupple or Row (In case we dont have joins) and on a result row of join (In case we have some joins.). So considering this in mind your current query is checking that for same row it should be 'Physics' and not 'Chemistry'. But this is not intended. So we need to traverse this table twice for comparison between year. Either in form of nested sub queries or in form of self join or in form of nested correlated sub queries. See Salil answer as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select distinct yr from nobel where subject='physics' and
            yr not in (select distinct yr from nobel where subject='chemistry')
```

Comment: thanks, it is working.. actually i dont knoe where to put 'not'